# How to use a Ubuntu 13.04 (amd64 .deb) program on 14.10

Tags: package-management, 14.10

I have a Toshiba L505D-S5965 laptop with Ubuntu 14.10, I am trying to install was the [Dolphin Emulator](http://www.dolphin-emu.org/download/) but all I see is the 13.04 (amd64 .deb) link. Is there some compatibility mode like Windows or will I have to wait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu has no 'reverse compatibility' mode, at least, not in the same sense as Windows does.  Even in Windows, the 'compatibility mode' does not account for older, non-compatible dependencies for programs.

To get older software installed into 14.10, you would have to download the `.deb` file, and attempt to install it.  You might run into issues such as dependencies being out of date, or too new, or just being totally obsolete and unavailable, in which case you have to then download each of those dependencies and install them manually.

When working with old software and ancient dependencies, as well, you will always run the risk of breaking your system.  I would suggest compiling the software from source, if they provide such a method to do so.  If using the older `.deb` is the only remaining option, then you are free to attempt to use it, but be warned you might not be able to install that because the dependencies for the software might all be gone, or your software is too new, or any number of other issues.

Comment: When I get the git code ( $ git clone https://github.com/dolphin-emu/dolphin.git) is that compiling it?

Comment: @kprovost7314 yes, so long as you follow the instructions in the README.  Note that for version updates you'll have to recompile, but it's more 'safe', I'd say, than relying on a package built for 13.04, which is well past End of LIfe.